# Jquery edit variables in a html string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a hidden template into a string variable in jquery and then edititng the variables before adding it back onto the page

Current code:

```
var htmlString = $("#hiddenDocumentsTemplate").html();
var html = htmlString.trim();

$(".Id input", html).attr("value", msg.succeeded.Id);
$(".plate input", html).attr("value", msg.succeeded.No);
$(".repair input", html).attr("value", msg.succeeded.Repair);
$(".mId input", html).attr("value", msg.succeeded.MId);
$(".StopStart input", html).attr("value", msg.succeeded.StopStart);

//$(".Id input", html).val(msg.succeeded.Id);
//$(".plate input", html).val(msg.succeeded.No);
//$(".repair input", html).val(msg.succeeded.Repair);
//$(".mId input", html).val(msg.succeeded.MId);
//$(".StopStart input", html).val(msg.succeeded.StopStart);

$(".selectUser input", html).val(msg.succeeded.SelectedUserId);
$(".selectStage input", html).val(msg.succeeded.SelectedStage);

$(".No", html).text(msg.succeeded.No);
$(".collect ").append(html);
```

Hidden Temp:

```
<div id="hiddenDocumentsTemplate"> 
   <input class="Id" id="Temp_0__Id" name="Temp[0].Id" type="hidden" value="307">
   <input class="plate" id="Temp_0__No" name="Temp[0].No" type="hidden" value="VTK">
   <input class="StopStart" id="Temp_0__StopStart" name="Temp[0].StopStart" type="hidden" value="False">
    <input class="repair" id="Temp_0__Repair" name="Temp[0].Repair" type="hidden" value="4775">
    <input class="mId" id="Temp_0__MId" name="Temp[0].MId" type="hidden" value="19">
    <div class="No">VTK</div>
    <div class="details">
        <select id="SelectedUserId" name="SelectedUserId" class="valid selectUser">
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="107" selected="">uzi</option>
        </select>
        <select id="SelectedStage" name="SelectedStage" class="valid selectStage">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
            </select>    
            <div class="button save">Update</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see i have tried a few things.

Comment: The second `jQuery()` parameter is context. In your example, `html` isn't a valid context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate the template as elements, you have to turn the string into elements.

(Use the `$.trim` method, as `String.trim` isn't available in all browsers.)

```
var html = $($.trim(htmlString));
```

Now the `html` variable is a jQuery object containing HTML elements that you can work with just as your code attempted. You can still use it in the `append` method, so there is no other changes needed in your code.

Comment: Any idea why this would not be working...$(".button", html).removeClass("False").addClass("True");

Comment: @Beginner: The element with `class="button"` doesn't have a class `False` in your example, but if it had, it would be removed. The class `True` would be added anyway.